# Difference between "stranded" and "waylaid"

Tags: meaning

What's the difference between "stranded passengers" and "waylaid passengers"?

EDIT:

I got ***waylaid passengers*** from [here](http://gma.yahoo.com/blind-passenger-81-causes-12-hour-emergency-landing-101506825--abc-news-topstories.html)

> Passengers were reportedly kept in the plane on the tarmac for an
>   extended period, without air conditioning, before being allowed into
>   the terminal. The airline then told **the waylaid passengers** that they
>   would be shuttled by bus five hours north to Dallas, because Spirit
>   does not operate a flight between Houston and Ft. Lauderdale.

If you read the article, you won't get any slightest idea that the passengers were being attacked or ambushed or anything close to being waylaid.

Comment: Is there something in particular about the dictionary entries for [strand](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/strand) and [waylay](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/waylay) that you are confused about?

Comment: I am not asking about strand and waylay, I am asking about stranded and waylaid. And I am asking in the context of passengers. Please, check the EDIT in my question.

Comment: @brilliant: these days [waylay](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/waylay?q=waylay) tends to be more synonymous with delay than ambush.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think originally *waylaid* did mean to be ambushed on the road.  But the result of being waylaid was that the ambushed parties were prevented or hindered from reaching their destination as planned.  Over time people began to use *waylay* whenever someone was hindered or prevented from reaching their destination especially when they felt it was due to someone's decision and not to an *act of god*.

[Here is a dictionary that does provide a reasonably fitting definition (2)](http://www.wordsmyth.net/?ent=waylay)

Answer (score 3):

I don’t think this is a good use of *waylaid*. The OED’s third definition is ‘to impede or intercept (a person) in his progress’. This suggests a deliberate attempt on the part of the waylayer to interfere with a traveller, possibly for a dubious purpose. This was presumably not the airline’s intention. *Stranded* or *delayed* would have removed any such implication.

Comment: Reading the news excerpt I collect that the journalist is suggesting negligent (though not necessarily intentional) behaviour on the airline side, so it fits with the OED definition you provide.

Comment: Oh, I have just read the full piece of news. Now waylaid makes more sense, though it does not refer to the airline, but to a passenger not mentioned in the excerpt.